# Eclipse editor runs slow on Ubuntu 16.04 after first project build

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, ubuntu

I've recently installed Ubuntu (16.04) I've noticed that after the first build of a project on Eclipse (I've tried this with Luna and Mars) that the editor starts to run slow.  There is a noticeable lag when typing and selecting text etc.  It doesn't make it unusable, but it is fairly irritating.  I've done the following to try and fix this, but to no avail:

- allocate more memory in `eclipse.ini`
- set the environment variable `$SWT_GTK3=0` (as I found something that said there may be a gtk3 bug in 16.04.
- update graphics drivers

At this point I'm really not sure what else to do.  It seems to run well at first, but after that first build (Java) it just dies a bit.  Any suggestions on what I could do to try and fix this would be much appreciated!

It's the first time I've used Eclipse with Ubuntu, as normally I'm on a Windows machine, so I'm not sure if maybe I've just not set something up properly.

Comment: monitor memory usage of eclipse using some profiles like `jconsole` or `jprofiler`

Comment: I see in java8 `jvisualvm` added for monitoring, good UI and features, seems extension of `jconsole`

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/761604/eclipse-not-working-in-16-04

Answer (score 1):

add the below lines into  the **eclipse.ini** file:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before the line:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```